# Copy Method of Range Class Failed copying data from external workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a table from an external workbook to my workbook and am getting the subject line error.
It occurs on the `rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination` line.

Is there anything I am missing?

```
 Sub ImportLogInfo()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range

    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

            Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Documents\Proposal Log Feeder\Modular Proposals Log.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True)
            Set rngSourceRange = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("Log").Range("DBtable")
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.Sheets("Log").Range("DBtable3")
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What happens if you only specify the top left cell as the destination rather than whole range?  rngDestination.Cells(1,1) for example?

Comment: Are you certain those ranges are defined properly?

Comment: `Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.Sheets("Log").Range("DBtable3").cells(1)` You should only require the top-left cell of a destination. Using the top-left cell avoids size mismatch problems. Actually, `rngDestination.cells(1)` might be better since you use rngDestination for other things later.

Comment: @Jeeped I just added the `.cell(1)` and that solved the problem. Thanks. Is there a way to stop it asking you so many questions when you are copying? It asks about there being data in the destination etc. Is there a code to skip this or do users have to keep hitting "enter"?

Comment: @Jeeped Can you turn your reply into an answer so you can get some credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only require the top-left cell of a destination. Using the top-left cell avoids size mismatch problems. Since you use rngDestination for other purposes later, just use .cells(1) when using it as the destination.

```
...
Set rngSourceRange = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("Log").Range("DBtable")
wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.Sheets("Log").Range("DBtable3")
rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination.cells(1)
---
```

I'm not entirely clear on which notifications and warnings you are receiving but you can try this at the top of your code.

```
application.displayalerts = false
```

Then turn them back on again with the following before exiting the sub procedure.

```
application.displayalerts = true
```